How to use old Flutter switch design?
I'm currently on the latest version of Flutter and Dart, but in my project, I want to use the old design of Flutter switches.
Current switch:
Current Flutter Switch Design
Old switch:
Old Flutter Switch Design
I tried using almost every attribute provided by Switch class in Flutter but couldn't get it back to the old design.
I've also searched pub.dev for relevant package but found none which can do this.

The new switch is following material 3 design, you can disable it for the whole app in MaterialApp's themeData.
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: false, //here
      );

Or if you still want to use the old design of the switch but want to keep the material 3 design for the app. try the following approach:
Theme(
          data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
          child: Switch(
            value: value,
            onChanged: (newValue) {},
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveThumbColor: Colors.red,
            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreen,
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),


The new switch design is due to Android updating its switch style. If you want
your switch to look like the old UI you should create a custom styled switch and make it look however you want.
e.g.
Switch(
  value: isSwitchOn,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      isSwitchOn = newValue;
    });
  },
  activeColor: Colors.green,
  inactiveThumbColor: Colors.red,
  activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreen,
  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
)


Actually, I'm using exactly what you suggested, but it only changes the colors of different entities on the switch, and I couldn't really render that old UI.

By default Material3 design is applied to Theme as well as Widgets:
So to use Switch or any other widget with old theme you can wrap your widget with Theme and in data property set data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false)
by setting useMateria3: false old theme will be used
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      child: Switch(
        value: isSwitchOn,
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            isSwitchOn = newValue;
          });
        },
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
    )

